My 404 page is blocked for indexing
My 404 page is blocked when I request for indexing in webmaster.
https://www.yarddiant.com/404.html
Please see the screenshot


This is by design.
The "soft 404" error occurs because Google believes it to be a 404 page, but since your link points directly to the (existent) 404.html template file, your server serves it up with a 200 OK status code rather than the 404 Not Found status code that it would use for any other nonexistent URL.
Basically, this is expected behavior. There is no reason to request a 404 page (or 404 page template) for indexing, and there is no reason for Google to index it. Thusly, Google refuses it for indexing.
